# Centering plotly output to html

Tags: r, plotly

I am programmatically writing a `plotly` widget to html. However, I can't seem to find an option for centering the resulting plot. Here's a representative example:

```
library( ggplot2 )

gg <- ggplot( mtcars, aes( x=mpg, y=wt ) ) + geom_point()
pp <- plotly::ggplotly( gg, width=300, height=300 )
htmlwidgets::saveWidget( pp, "test.html" )
```

Note that the resulting output is left-aligned on the page:

[image]

I've looked through the options of `ggplotly`, `plotly::layout` and `saveWidget`, but there's no immediately apparent way to center the plot. In the past, I've wrapped `plotly` elements inside Rmarkdown documents and used markdown keywords to center the plot. However, the current `plotly` output is generated dynamically as part of a larger framework that is not trivial to wrap inside Rmarkdown. Is there a way to introduce centering tags when writing `plotly` widgets to .html?

Comment: I think you can wrap <center> in result file. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks, Krzysztof. To make sure I understand correctly, are you suggesting to edit the output .html file by hand? I am looking for a programmatic solution, because I may be outputting a dozen .html files at a time, and it would be too time-consuming to edit each one manually.

Comment: No! Just check out where you want to insert <center> (count bytes) and where you want to close it (from the end)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Krzystof. It seems this may actually be possible to do within `R` using `htmlwidgets::prependContent` and `htmlwidgets::appendContent`. I just haven't quite figured out how to use those two functions correctly yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way I found was to wrap the output of `ggplotly` inside a `div` tag, using `htmltools` package. The resulting HTML object can be saved to a file using `save_html` from the same package:

```
pp <- plotly::ggplotly( gg, width=300, height=300 )    # As before
ppc <- htmltools::div( pp, align="center" )  # Result is now an HTML object
htmltools::save_html( ppc, "test.html" )     # Use in place of htmlwidgets::saveWidget()
```

Here's the result, now properly centered:

[image]